# Delete data in Angular2 app in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angular, angular2-http

How would one delete data from a MySql database using PHP code in an Angular2 application? The closest advice is for Angular 1 and is as follows:

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function(id){

    // ask the user if he is sure to delete the record
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        // post the id of product to be deleted
        $http.post('delete_product.php', {
            'id' : id
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){

            // tell the user product was deleted
            Materialize.toast(data, 4000);

            // refresh the list
            $scope.getAll();
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use the `post` method similarly:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private  http: Http) {}

  deleteData() {
    return this.http.post('delete_record.php')         
  }
}
```

Any insight/experience with Angular2/PHP would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the http post works similarly in angular2. Since you want to use post, i guess you also want to add a body to the request.

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular/core';
import { Http } from 'angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private  http: Http) {}

  deleteData(data: SomeObject) {
    let url = "delete_record.php";
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http.post(url, body)
       .subscribe(
          result => console.log(result),
          error => console.error(error)
       );
  }
}
```

You can also send a delete request, which would be "best practice".

```
 return this.http.delete(url)
        .subscribe(
           result => console.log(result),
           error => console.error(error)
        });
```

More about the http-client here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html